# Database Schema for Pricing Products (packages, promotions, qty based, limited time offer…)

Tags: database, web-applications, database-design, schema

I'm working on a new point of sale for a company that products for different prices depending on the product mix.

All products have a base price.

To explain my problem, I will use the following info:

```
Product         Category        Price
A               1               45
B               1               70
Q               2               20
R               2               27
S               2               15
X               3               17
Y               3               22
Z               3               16
```

The company has Packages, for example Package "Combo": for product A or B, if you choose 1 of Q or R and 1 of X, Y or Z you get a $20 discount.

**Case A:** Sometimes customers add on to a base product when placing an order, for example:
They wan't one of Product A, and they add Product Q and Product P to that to create a package that has a discounted price. Then they might add that they want 1 of product B with 1 R and 1 Z.

**Case B:** Sometimes customers will add 1 A and 2 B, 2 Q, 1 S, 2 X and 1 Z. According to the rules set forth by "Combo" Package, only 2 combos would apply because S is not a combo item.

Other promotions are dependent on quantity, so if you buy 2 of B you get 20% off and/or dependent upon time, it is only valid after 5 PM or before 10% off if before 10am. Another promotion might depend on when your last purchase occured or if you have purchase more than $X in Y timeframe.

**My Problems:**

1) How do I structure the tables so I my create the different packages or promotions in a way that is very flexible to add different types of promotions with different requirements?

2) When they order like Case B (or a mix of Case A and Case B) how do I structure my query so that I can test to see what product mix(es) are in the order, and update the prices/descriptions accordingly? Ultimately, the best result for this query would return which packages and promotions have requirements fulfilled in order of which gives the most benefit to the customer (i.e. maybe what they ordered fulfills requirements for promotion 1 and 3, but promotion 3 is less expensive. This must work with multiple promotions).

Thanks in advance for the help!

**UPDATE #1**

To better describe the problems at hand and to update the work done thus far to solve them [I'm incluiding an ERD of the Product Model limited to the entities and attributes that affect the issue](http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/4732703) (i.e. inventory is not at play here, so no inventory entities are present).

I'm also including sample data from the entities and attributes that affect this question (to simplify reading the data, I'm putting in name/descriptions in place of Foreign Keys):

[Here is a link to a flow chart giving an example of a combo, a fast and visual way to understand the table structure.](http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/4732791)

```
PRODUCT
---------
ID  Name
================================
1   Hamburger
2   Cheeseburger
3   Bacon Hamburger
4   Bacon Cheeseburger
5   Orange Juice
6   Apple Juice
7   Coffee
8   Coke
9   French Fries
10  Onion Rings
11  Soup du Jour
12  Hamburger Combo
13  CheeseBurger Combo
14  Bacon Hamburger Combo
15  Bacon Cheeseburger Combo
16  Combo Side
17  Combo Beverage
18  Small Orange Juice
19  Large Orange Juice
20  Small Apple Juice
21  Large Apple Juice
22  Add Extra Patty
23  Add Avocado

PRODUCT COMPONENT
------------------
productFrom                 productTo       
===================================================
Hamburger Combo             Hamburger
Hamburger Combo             Combo Side
Hamburger Combo             Combo Beverage
CheeseBurger Combo          Cheeseburger
CheeseBurger Combo          Combo Side
CheeseBurger Combo          Combo Beverage
Bacon Hamburger Combo       Bacon Hamburger
Bacon Hamburger Combo       Combo Side
Bacon Hamburger Combo       Combo Beverage
Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Bacon Cheeseburger
Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Combo Side
Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Combo Beverage

PRODUCT FEATURE
----------------
ID  Description
=======================
1   Combo Side Option
2   Combo Beverage
3   Juice
4   Orange Juice Size
5   Apple Juice Size
6   Extras

PRODUCT FEATURE APPLICABILITY
------------------------------
product                     productFeature  ProductFeatureApplicabilityType
============================================================================
Hamburger Combo             Combo Side      Required
Hamburger Combo             Juice Flavor    Required
Cheeseburger Combo          Combo Side      Required
Cheeseburger Combo          Juice Flavor    Required
Bacon Hamburger Combo       Combo Side      Required
Bacon Hamburger Combo       Juice Flavor    Required
Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Combo Side      Required
Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Juice Flavor    Required


PRODUCT FEATURE APPLICABILITY
------------------------------
productFeature  product             ProductFeatureApplicabilityType
============================================================================
Combo Side      Hamburger Combo             Required
Combo Beverage  Hamburger Combo             Required
Extras          Hamburger Combo             Optional
Combo Side      Cheeseburger Combo          Required
Combo Beverage  Cheeseburger Combo          Required
Extras          Cheeseburger Combo          Optional
Combo Side      Bacon Hamburger Combo       Required
Combo Beverage  Bacon Hamburger Combo       Required
Extras          Bacon Hamburger Combo       Optional
Combo Side      Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Required
Combo Beverage  Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Required
Extras          Bacon Cheeseburger Combo    Optional




OPTIONAL FEATURE
------------------
productFeatureFrom  Product             ProductFeatureTo        
=============================================================
Combo Side Option   French Fries
Combo Side Option   Onion Rings
Combo Side Option   Soup du Jour
Combo Beverage                          Juice
Combo Beverage      Coffee
Juice                                   Orange Juice Size
Juice                                   Apple Juice Size
Orange Juice Size   Orange Apple Juice
Orange Juice Size   Orange Apple Juice
Apple Juice Size    Small Apple Juice
Apple Juice Size    Large Apple Juice
Extras              Add Extra Patty
Extras              Add Avocado
```

So, with the research and support provided by the community up until know, I have been able to solve Problem #1. In fact, I have done so with more flexibility than I thought I could do in the first deployment of the system.

All though there have been advances with Problem 2, it is not solved to satisfaction. There have been some ideas on how to do this, [Neil McGuilgan asked a great question leading towards a possible solution using Relational Division](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/what-is-the-name-of-this-type-of-query-and-what-is-an-efficient-example) and [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237) helped a lot. However this solution at present, and as I understand it, only works with "one" record (combo) at a time. If a customer Walks up and says he wants 2 cheeseburgers, 1 hamburger, 1 small Apple Juice, 1 Coke, 1 French Fries and 2 onion Rings, I need a way to detect that there is only one combo in the mix and add the other products at base price. If there are multiple combo combinations, I'm looking (ideally for an sql query) that can prioritize combo combinations by largest savings.

One idea I've come up with to solve problem two is to add and attribute to PRODUCT COMPONENT flaggin the main product for the combo (i.e. hamburger). Then when running the pricing process, query what products in the order are main products in a "package", relating the query to the discount given by the PRICE COMPONENT table and ordering by that value (descending), and in that order of packages check to see if you can create a "package" with the remaining non-main products with a query and loop the process until there are no more main products or there are no more non-main products in the remainder.

Comment: Chapter 3 of http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0471380237 has your answer.

Comment: Hi Neil. Thanks for your recommendation. I bought the book and read chapters 1 and 3, and skimmed through several other chapters including the appendixes with the table/column suggestions. It helped a great deal with the first part of my problem (data modeling). What I'm still stumped with is part 2, how I'm going to structure a query to determine what combination of PRODUCTs with PRODUCT FEATUREs is the best value for a customer (refer to Case B in my question for an example of this).

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I'm thinking maybe what I'm looking for is something  along the lines of figure 3.9b, but the application or examples of that figure is to short for me to fully grasp how to solve my problem. I'm hoping you can help me out pointing me in the direction of another chapter that might contain more info regarding what I want to achieve or help me understand how to apply the PRODUCT ASSOCIATION concept to Case B in my question.

Comment: Maybe another way to put Case A and Case B in the terms used by the book: Case A: A customer orders a PRODUCT, and while on that PRODUCT selects optional PRODUCT FEATUREs for the product and the price is updated accordingly. Maybe the customer selects optional PRODUCT FEATUREs a and b for PRODUCT Z and the total turns up at $12, but product Y includes PRODUCT FEATUREs a and b for a total of $11. For Case B: a customer adds several qtys of PRODUCTs Y,Z,a and b. How can I program the system to detect that there is a PRODUCT 'combo Z' that contains PRODUCT FEATUREs a and b and...

Comment: so if I order a burger $5, fries $3, beer $5, and sundae $4 (total $17), and there is a burger-fries-beer combo $10, you want to be able to find that combo and update the price to $14?

Comment: ...that product is less expensive than buying PRODUCT 'combo Y' that also includes PRODUCT FEATUREs a and b.

Comment: You are correct in your understanding of your burger-fries-beer combo example. That is what I need to achieve.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to be able to chat :(

Comment: Regarding finding the combo by its products, see here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-query-and-what-is-an-efficient-example

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thanks for the link! very helpfull. I'm doing some TDD with the full product model from Silverston's book. I decided to test with the model to see if I scratch the one I'd been working with because it offers so much flexibility.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan  I'm hoping you can help me clarify something. Product Features are set up in a way that you can have more than one per product (i.e. size [small,large] and color [blue,green]), and can use the price component to relate and update price variations accordingly. So I would need 4 records on the product feature entity, 4 on price component (if pricing changes from base price). Am I correct up to this poing? The first problem I have with this implementation is in ORDER ITEM, there is only one attribute for PRODUCT FEATURE.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan It mentions an example for PRODUCT FEATUREs that is very suited for the garment industry, and it is one some of my issues can relate to. It is regarding size [small, medium, large], but then, if you want to track inventory per size, it doesn't seem to be contemplated in the models. For this type of functionality do you have to set up each size as a different product? This gives me a issues, because I have several products that have to be customized and you are prompted to customize when selected. Something like: select laptop, select processor, select hard drive, select ram.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I think I resolved the order Item issue, Use one row for the productID and then N rows for productFeatureIDs. ??? what do you think of this approach?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Work in progress... Found a table in the appendix called "Optional Feature", I think the way to employ this table is to have the base product as a "category-type" (i.e. white shirt), then via a productFeature with optionality (i.e. size), select a size that is really another product (white shirt small). To solve the inventory issue, don't track inventory for the base "category-type" productID. For reporting, can run reports on both the base product and features (sizes). Does that sound solid?